# excel rows, find if include, low and high

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

[[image]

<sub>Click for full-size image</sub>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53iaR.jpg)

**For what is marked in orange:**

As mentioned in the example in the picture it says "headphones". I would like to search through all the lines in column A, to find something that has that name in it. Then it should count the number of people and come out with the number (in how many) 
the "middle price" I want it to take the price of B (depending on where it found it called headphones) and take the average price of it.

In column *secured*, I would like to count how many of them (from the number, or from the beginning) that have "secured" as "no" and "yes."

I would like to use this on several things.

**For what is marked in pink:**

Where would I find the average price of all the goods, and what the name of the particular item is? Same with the highest and lowest price.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to build a pivot table. In the source data, you need to add a column for the category, for example "headphones" or "ipad" as the values for each row. Then you can create a pivot table. Drag the category into the row labels. Drag them again into the values area to create a count. Drag the price into the values and change the value field settings to calculate the Minimum.

Etc.

Pivot tables are very powerful and can produce such reports without any formulas, using a few clicks.

Here is a [link to a sample file](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=FE479525195477F7!633&authkey=!APkQVPr7dVacbhA)

The data has three additional helper columns compare to your data, so there are values for the category and numbers for the secured and unsecured columns.

[image]

Comment: Hi Teylyn. Could you provide me an examble-excel document with this?

Comment: one example document in excel

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a screenshot and link to a sample file.